# trick SQL to read data as true instead of false

Tags: sql, query-builder, adhoc

I have searched everywhere online before asking this:

I'm self-teaching how to build a report that makes it easier for my co-workers. I wanted to pull a report for the clients that never attended. We use last_bill_svc_date, but the problem is I have been facing was that there is a certain visit type that is non-billable due to the client being a self-pay.

Is there a way for me to trick SQL into thinking that a visit type is true for a billable service date?

I'm using two different tables and I am hoping that is all I needed in order to pull a never attended report. I have 17 visit type ID number that I need it to be true for billable at all time.

I'm using Custom AD Hoc provided by Credible for Electronic Health Records "Query builder 2.0" is what I use.

Any help is greatly appreciated and I will clarify as best as I can. It is my goal to show the last billable service date to be null so I can count how many members that have not attended the centers yet.

**EDIT**

I'm not entirely sure how to show an example, but I'll do my best.

```
client_id    first_name    last_name    last_bill_svc_date
--------------------------------------------------
1              A-firstname A-lastname    Null  
2              B-firstname B-lastname    Null  
3              C-firstname C-lastname    Null  
4              D-firstname D-lastname    Null  
5              E-firstname E-lastname    Null  
6              F-firstname F-lastname    Null  
7              G-firstname G-lastname    Null  
8              H-firstname H-lastname    Null  
9              I-firstname I-lastname    Null
```

I actually was able to pull the exact record above, but it ignores the one with self-paying visit type.

I once used WHERE statement as in

```
Where (ClientVisit.visittype_id In ('514', '519', '527', '533', '509',
  '500', '528', '540', '529', '511', '506', '513', '545', '530', '510', '512',
  '507') And Clients.client_status = 'active')
```

The visit type is the one I wanted it to focus on, but it, unfortunately, focus on billable visit type and ignores the non-billable. I wanted to be able to force SQL to read the specific visit type to be billable no matter what. I struggle to figure out which column I need to gather info from since Credible's custom AD HOC has 11 pages worth of tables. As of now, I'm using two tables: Clients and ClientVisit

**EDIT Part Two**

```
    Select Clients.client_id As client_id,
  Clients.last_name,
  Clients.first_name,
  Clients.last_bill_svc_date
From Clients
Where Clients.client_id In (Select ClientVisit.client_id
  From ClientVisit) And Clients.client_status = 'active'
```

This is the code I currently have on the list with a help of a friend. It showed a result of 47 members that have not attended to one of the centers. In the spreadsheet, I just showed BLANK result for last_bill_svc_date.

I did a report coming from "Advanced Search Report" that was provided in Credible where I select the encounter types that I know it is billable. While I know sticking with advanced search report is probably the best way to go. The reason for me to switching over to Export Tool where I can run the report from SQL Query Builder 2.0 because I will be able to have it showed the client's primary team only instead of doing it manually when I go through the Advanced Search Report.

The Result I want to see is as follows:

Client's first and last name,

Client's start date (So, we know how long member has been an active member and still haven't attended)

last billable service date (I'll filter it to be NULL),

Primary Team (Each client is only allowed to have one primary team, but they can be assigned to multiple teams).

I realized that visit id number 528 has a lot of self-pay, which forced the visit type to be non-billable in Credible. That's when I want to force it to read it as if ID '528' is billable even though it claims that it is non-billable.

Another reason for wanting to specify the visit type because we provide billable phone services where we can do outreach to clients. Clearly, that doesn't count as client's attendance to one of the centers.

It has to be something so simple to get it working the way I want to see. Otherwise, I'll have to accept and continue using Advanced Search Report feature.

Comment: share sample data and expected output with RDMS name

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin I have added the sample. I'm terrible at this, but I hope it helps clarify it a bit.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the task. There are active clients and their visits. You want to show certain clients depending on the visits. Do you look at a certain date or do you look at the last visit per client or what else? Then how does that billing thing come into play? Is there a column that indicates billable or not? Or does the absence of a visit record indicate billable or non-billable  somehow? I must admit I have no idea.

Comment: Sample data would be: some client records. Some client visit records. Then show us the expected result, where some of the sample clients are in the result and others are not, and you tell us why. (E.g.: "Client 1 is in the results because the last visit was of type 514. And 514 is in the list. Client 2 is not in the results because the last visit was of type 515. And 515 is not in the list. Client 3 is in the results because the last visit was of type 200. Types 200 and 400 mean not billable, so we ignore these and look at the visit before that instead and it's 519, which is in the list."

Comment: I do realize that my sample wasn't clear. Let me see if I can get it updated. I apologize for not being clear in advance.